# Link to "Plans and pricing" page at GitHub

Tags: github

How can I click-out my way to "[Plans and pricing](https://github.com/pricing)" page? Is there any link leading to this page on my repo's page or anywhere else? I can't see it in standard GitHub footer.

Each time I need to open this page (I can' remember URL) I have to use Google, because I can't find link to it on any GitHub page. Isn't that a little bit strange? Am I blind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not logged in (or you open [github.com](https://github.com/) in a private tab), you'll see a line saying:

> "Upgraded plans starts at $x/mo."

This will take you to https://github.com/plans which eventually becomes the one you are looking for.

Comment: Does this mean, that when I'm logged in (always; that's GitHub usage point IMHO) there is no way (no link) to get to this page, except for hand-writing URL to browser's address bar or using Google? Sounds strange...

Comment: Once logged in you can see plan prices @  https://github.com/account/plans (yet there is no much more info there). why? well, I claim no knowledge on why they choose to do it this way :/

Comment: Yes, but that page lists only all plans in your current path -- either Private or Organisational. You can't see plans from other group. OK, we have an answer -- Google or typing URL are the only ways. There is link to plans page, once you're logged in. Strange, but true.